# How to group a list of objects into a Map of Map based on object's attributes in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects that I want to convert to a map of maps.

```
class A {
  String aProp;
  String bProp;
  String cProp;
}
```

then I have `List<A> aList`.
and I am trying to convert them into a map -

```
Map<aProp, Map<bProp, cProp>>
```

how can I achieve this?
I tried `Collectors.groupingBy` but still not able to achieve what I want.

Comment: `Map<aProp, Map<bProp, cProp>>` makes no sense. Your properties have type `String`, so the result would be a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`. And if you tried `Collectors.groupingBy`, show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `aProp` and `bProp` combinations are unique:

```java
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = aList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                a -> a.aProp,
                Collectors.toMap(a -> a.bProp, a -> a.cProp)
        ));
// map ==> {1={2=3}, 2={3=4}, 3={4=5}}
```

If there are instances with the same values for `aProp` and `bProp`, then the `toMap` collector will cause an exception to be thrown. If that's going to happen you can use one of the other `toMap` methods. For instance, `toMap(a -> a.bProp, a -> a.cProp, (x, y) -> y))` will take the last value (although the order doesn't guarantee what that "last value" will be).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a for-loop on `List<A>`, adding a new map entry for each iteration.

```java
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map(List<A> aList) {
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (A a : aList) map.put(a.aProp, Map.of(a.bProp, a.cProp));
    return map;
}
```

Example output

```
{a={b=c}, d={e=f}, g={h=i}, j={k=l}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
    private String aProp;
    private String bProp;
    private String cProp;

    public A(String aProp, String bProp, String cProp) {
        this.aProp = aProp;
        this.bProp = bProp;
        this.cProp = cProp;
    }

    public String getaProp() {
        return aProp;
    }

    public String getbProp() {
        return bProp;
    }

    public String getcProp() {
        return cProp;
    }

}

List<A> listOfA = List.of(new A("r", "b", "c"), new A("r", "b", "d"),
          new A("t", "b", "e"), new A("t", "c", "f"),
          new A("r", "d", "g"), new A("w", "b", "j"));
```

Here is what you requested.

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();

for (A a : listOfA) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(a.getaProp(), v -> new HashMap<>())
    .put(a.getbProp(), a.getcProp());
}

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println();
```

prints

```
r={b=d, d=g}
t={b=e, c=f}
w={b=j}
```

Notice that since instances of `A` had duplicate `aProp's` and `bProp's` the next one encountered replaced the previous one.
In the previous example, `b,d for r` replaced `b,c for r`.

To prevent this, if required, you can create an `ArrayList<String>` as the value for the inner map.

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
for (A a : listOfA) { 
     map2.computeIfAbsent(a.getaProp(), v -> new HashMap<>())
         .computeIfAbsent(a.getbProp(), v -> new ArrayList<>())
             .add(a.getcProp());
}

map2.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
r={b=[c, d], d=[g]}
t={b=[e], c=[f]}
w={b=[j]}
```

In this example, `c` was preserved in the ArrayList.